# Docker "module" error on express-based node app

Tags: node.js

I learn about node-js and Docker. Since the beginning of this journey, I have developed incrementally [this library](https://github.com/quivero/quivero-api). I can:

1. Write a NodeJS app;
2. Extend it to an express web app;
3. Write a docker-compose.yml;
4. Write a DockerFile;

So far, so good. Since we want to production-publish it, we run the command `docker build -t IMAGE_NAME . && docker-compose up`. The following error pops out:

```
Starting nodejs ... done
Attaching to nodejs
nodejs    | [nodemon] 2.0.15
nodejs    | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
nodejs    | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
nodejs    | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
nodejs    | [nodemon] starting `node app.js ./src/index.js`
nodejs    | /home/node/app/src/index.js:2
nodejs    | import express from 'express';
nodejs    |        ^^^^^^^
nodejs    | 
nodejs    | SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
nodejs    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
nodejs    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
nodejs    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
nodejs    |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
nodejs    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
nodejs    |     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
nodejs    |     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
nodejs    |     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

It seems a silly mistake I make, but at this point, I am still very novice to notice it. I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Node.js v10 doesn't support `import` at all, you should use a more recent version of Node.js

Comment: Do you mind improving Daniel's answer on the subject?

Comment: They'll have to do that themselves.

Comment: How will they do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with your Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN npm install

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
```

You're running `npm install` before setting your `WORKDIR`. Have you tried running `echo $PWD`?

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN echo $PWD
```

You probably just need to set your `WORKDIR` first, since you probably want to run `npm install` in there.

Your volumes look like they might cause some issues too:

```
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
```

You're creating a volume that will sync the node_modules you have installed into the container. This isn't what we want, because we want to set as much as we can inside the Dockerfile.

```
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - /home/node/app/node_modules
```

Doing this will prevent `node_modules` from being sync'd, which would overwrite anything you had installed by including `RUN npm install` in your Dockerfile.

If you make these changes, you should be alright.

Comment: I give will make the changes you provide. I normally enter in panic-mode when working with Docker. :/

Comment: We've all been there. There's a whole new set of skills to learn (Docker, Docker Compose) just to set up a new Linux machine (image/container). Keep with it, because Docker is very common nowadays.

Comment: It is very straight to the point. So straight that the workflow branching is very branchy.

Comment: @danieldaughterty do you mind editing it yourself? I performed the modifications you claim, but it does not solve the issue.